getting error while entering data through selenium java program
Why does Selenium WebDriver fail to enter a value in an input field?
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.zoho.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("login_id")).sendKeys("username@example.com");

I'm trying to enter the value in the input field of login id when enter image description herei run the program it not entering the value on input field......

you're on the wrong page, the login field is on this page https://accounts.zoho.com/signin

Hi dipak! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I have checked your code and found that the problem is after clicking sign in button you are not waiting for email field is to be clickable.
Here is the working version code you need
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://www.zoho.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='login']")).click();

    By txtEmail = By.id("login_id");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(txtEmail));

    WebElement loginElement = driver.findElement(txtEmail);
    loginElement.sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
    System.out.println(loginElement);

I only added Explicit wait to check the email field until clickable and entered the text.
Also a friendly suggestion use selenium latest version 4.22.0 that is why i removed webdrivermanager from the code which is not needed in latest version
Here is the screenshot for your reference
